# Magento2 - Destination fields are not mapped. Document: paypal_settlement_report_row. Fields: store_id

Tags: paypal, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, magento1.9.3, magento2.3.4

I tried to do migration from Magento1.9.3.8 to Magento2.3.4, when I ran the Magento Data migration tool I always got this error:

> Destination fields are not mapped. Document:
>   paypal_settlement_report_row. Fields: store_id

I tried to fix it by modifying the `map_file` in `etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/map.xml.dist`, but no luck

```
<destination>
     ....
     <field_rules>
         ....
         <ignore>
            <datatype>paypal_settlement_report_row.store_id</datatype>
        </ignore>
    </field_rules>
</destination>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **--auto** to skip this error like below.

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/config.xml
```